# Why is Finn's designation FN-xxxx?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, stormtroopers

In *The Force Awakens* we see that stormtroopers are given designations, and that Finn's is FN-2187. I'm not so interested in the numbers given, as I assume they are just to distinguish between troopers (although Finn's numerical designation had an [interesting back story](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/finn-john-boyega-george-lucas-fn-2187/)).

Why are they prefixed with *FN* specifically? Out of universe,  I can understand it means we can rename FN-2187 as Finn. But what does it mean in in-universe ?

Nb. I understand you'll need some other designation so as not to be limited to 9,999 troops. I'm more interested in specifically *why the letters FN*.

Comment: You mean something like **CC** for ***C**lone **C**ommando* or **CT** for ***C**lone **T**rooper*?? My guess would be something like the **F**irst Order's 14th batch of Troopers (since N=14, if A=1)??

Comment: My guess would be that they started with AA-0000, AA-0001 .... FN-2187...

Comment: @RickSanchez that could also be true. But in-universe, it'd make sense that "FN" had an actual meaning, in the same way that CC, CT, ARC, and so on design their hierarchy in the Republic's army.

Comment: It could also be possible that "FN" makes reference to their assigned Star Destroyer: the _Finalizer_.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández that would mean that this one star destroyer had at least 2187 strom troopers on board?

Comment: @Thomas the Wikia says it has at least 8000 stormtroopers, as stated in _Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections_.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández that sounds like the start of a good answer

Comment: @AlfredoHernández in Before the Awakening Finn has the FN distinction before they are deployed to the Star Destroyer and before he was made a full Storm Trooper, it seems unlikely they would've ear marked a batch for a particular Star Destroyer before seeing how many graduated.

Comment: @NikolaiDante you are right. I was precisely checking it now to see it they mentioned the Finalizer anywhere. I guess, then, that this question doesn't have an official answer as of now.

Comment: @BMWurm - that sounds like an awsome theory! Do you mind if I steal it to incorporate into my answer? (since we already have FN and FO, they seem like they are sequential)

Comment: @DVK Not at all, go for it :)